# Hashset to keys and values

Tags: powershell, hashset

I have a problem in my script:

here I set a var remotefilehash:

```
$remotefilehash = $remotefiles -replace '^[a-f0-9]{32}(  )', '$0=  ' | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

this creates a hashtable

I then compare those hash's to what I have locally in a hashset

```
# Create a hash set from the local hashes.

$localHashSet = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]] $localmd5

# Loop over all remote hashes to find those not among the local hashes.
$diffmd5 = $remotefilehash.Keys.Where({ -not $localHashSet.Contains($_) })
```

this gets me the hashkeys but I subsequently also need to get the hash values for those keys that are found in the above where ...

Comment: The keys _are the hash values_

Comment: updated with a sub question as I think this isn't doing the diff properly

Comment: Please don't "re-use" questions, just [ask a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and reference this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> this creates a hashtable

Actually, it creates an *array* of [hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables), because [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata) turns *each pipeline input object* into a separate hashtable.

To create a *single* hashtable, join the input lines to form a *single* string first - note how `` -join "`n" `` is applied to the result of the `-replace` operation in order to form a single, multi-line string:

```
$remotefilehash = 
  ($remotefiles -replace '^[a-f0-9]{32}(  )', '$0=  ' -join "`n") |
     ConvertFrom-StringData
```

---

To enumerate the *key-value pairs* instead of just the *keys* (`.Keys`) of a hashtable(-like) object, you need to use its `.GetEnumerator()` method:

```
$diffmd5 = 
  $remotefilehash.GetEnumerator().Where({ -not $localHashSet.Contains($_.Key) })
```

The reason that an enumerator must be requested *explicitly* is that PowerShell by default considers a hashtable/dictionary a *single* object that is passed *as a whole* through the pipeline / passed to enumeration methods such as the [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where) and [`.ForEach()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach) array methods.

Note that the output of the above command is *not* itself a hashtable, but a regular, array-like collection (of type [`[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection-1)) whose elements happen to be key-value pair objects.
As such, this output *is* enumerated in the pipeline.

Comment: OK a wee bit late but I think there's an issue with this hashset process - going to update the original post

Comment: @Tony, your updated code is missing the `-join "`n"` part, so `$remotefilehash` is still not a _single_ hashtable. Generally - unless there's a problem with the answer itself - it's better to create a _new_ question post for follow-up questions.

Comment: let me just ask a new quesetion with said new issue