# Error with hashtable join and covertFrom String

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I'm using the code referenced here: with the examples etc but I'm running into an error with this line:

```
$remotefilehash =  ($remotefiles -replace '^[a-f0-9]{32}(  )', '$0=  ' -join "`n") | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69782527/800592

here's the full error:

```
ConvertFrom-StringData : Data item '4826367e20469078693dced6dc642b96' in line '4826367e20469078693dced6dc642b96  =  My Videos/Drone/DJI-FPV/DJI_0003.MP4' is already defined. 
At P:\scripts\code\pcloud_sync.ps1:66 char:86
+ ... ace '^[a-f0-9]{32}(  )', '$0=  ' -join "`n") | ConvertFrom-StringData
+                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [ConvertFrom-StringData], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromStringDataCommand
```

***Update2***
I think my desire is to deduplicate my `remoteFiles` object which is simply an list/arry? of md5sum  file path. since it seems like there are times where there is the same file in two different paths I want to de duplicate the remoteFiles obj on the md5sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata) parses each input string in the form of one or more `<name>=<value>` lines into a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables).

In doing so it *doesn't tolerate duplicates*; that is, if a previous `<name>` value is encountered *again* in a given input string, the statement-terminating error you saw occurs.

A simple repro:

```bash
# !! Error: 
# !!  "ConvertFrom-StringData: Data item 'Key' in line 'Key=b' is already defined"
ConvertFrom-StringData "Key=a`nKey=b"
```

Thus, the solution is to eliminate duplicates from your input string first - assuming that the `<value>` part among the lines with duplicate `<name>`s is *also* the same.

If not, you'll need a different data structure to represent your input data, which `ConvertFrom-StringData` cannot provide.

If you only care about the `<name>` parts - ignoring duplicates, irrespective of their `<value>`s - you can parse them into a [`[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[T]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.HashSet-1) instance; in your case:

```bash
$remotefileHashSet =
  [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]] $remotefiles.ForEach({ (-split $_)[0] })
```

Note that hash sets are case-*sensitive* by default with respect to lookups; more work is needed if you want case-insensitivity: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67663212/45375).

Comment: interesting - the sum's are the same but the paths are different which I don't really care about - how do I dedup by just the sum?

Comment: @Tony, please see my update.

Comment: updated original post, as I don't think what your proposing gets me what I need ?

Comment: if the above wasn't clear I need the sum and the path so removing just the dupes from the sum's leaves me with an issue matching up the paths ...

Comment: @Tony, your first comment on this question contradicts your most recent one. As stated in the answer, if you have `<name>=<value>` pairs with duplicate `<name>`s but different `<value>`s and you want to _retain_ these duplicates, `ConvertFrom-StringData` as shown won't work. _Swapping_ keys and values  may be an option, with the file paths acting as the keys, and the corresponding hashes as the values. It sounds like it may be time for a _new_ question post yet again.